# Principal component analysis (PCA) assumptions

Tags: k-means, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I used PCA to reduce a 180 dimensions feature space in 3 principal components.
Afterwards I used k-mean clustering to cluster the data according to the 3 principal components of PCA.

I read in wikipedia that principal components are guaranteed to be independent if the data set is jointly normally distributed. I didn't calculate the jointly distribution of all my features (180)...is that a problem?

Which are the assumptions (if any) or the best practices in using PCA for dimensionality reductions?

Comment: as a side note, in your dimensionality reduction you could be interested in checking how much the first 3 dimensions contribute to the variance, see for example http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31911

Comment: @lib thanks for your comment...I already do this and the first 3 components contribute for the 60% of the total variance in the data.